# Android camera fail to connect to service

Tags: android, video, android-camera

I' ve a problem when my app is opening because when the app is opening crushed, the problem is that the camerasource is not null or something like that and is not working on all the phones.

These are the errors:

> 10-15 00:35:17.164 11270-11270/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>                                                                                                               at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
>                                                                                                               at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:423)
>                                                                                                               at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:384)
>                                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.zzchq(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.start(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview.startIfReady(CameraSourcePreview.java:99)
>                                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview.access$200(CameraSourcePreview.java:34)
>                                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview$SurfaceCallback.surfaceCreated(CameraSourcePreview.java:122)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:606)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:692)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
>                                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5313)
>                                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

These is the function that crash the app:

```
private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
    if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
        if (mOverlay != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            if (isPortraitMode()) {
                // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                // 90 degrees
                mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
            } else {
                mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
            }
            mOverlay.clear();
        }
        mStartRequested = false;
    }
}
```